# Downloading large files from alfresco

Tags: java, jboss, alfresco, spring-portlet-mvc, heap-size

I am working on Alfresco Web Content Repository. I am writing a portal application which uses alfresco web service api's to communicate to alfresco. I am writing code to download files from alfresco to local system. I am using PortletOuputStream as an output stream and using jboss Gate in portal as a portal server. But when i am downloading large files(greter than 63M)  i am gettin Heap space error.

This  problem can be solved by increasing jboss heap space.But i want to do without increasing that. Though i am reading in chunks i am getting this error.

Kindly let me know how to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you buffering the whole file in memory, or are you streaming out to disk as you go?

Comment: Reduce your chunk size and dont buffer file in memory